# Regular expression to match linear-gradient and its content from a string

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I get computed background style of an element and the result is like this:

```
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(126, 47, 182, 0) 0%, rgba(126, 47, 182, 0) 25%, rgba(249, 71, 157, 0) 80%, rgba(249, 71, 157, 0) 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box
```

What regular expression can I use to match only **linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(126, 47, 182, 0) 0%, rgba(126, 47, 182, 0) 25%, rgba(249, 71, 157, 0) 80%, rgba(249, 71, 157, 0) 100%)**

Comment: the goal is to extract the part that I selected in bold -> linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(126, 47, 182, 0) 0%, rgba(126, 47, 182, 0) 25%, rgba(249, 71, 157, 0) 80%, rgba(249, 71, 157, 0) 100%)

Comment: Looks like famfamfam got the answer here: [swift split css linear-gradient using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70677799/3345375)

Comment: Also related: [parse css gradient rule with Javascript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20215440/3345375)

Comment: And: [How does one extract the color-stop values from a string which contains the definition of a linear gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67065689/how-does-one-extract-the-color-stop-values-from-a-string-which-contains-the-defi)

Answer (score 3):

Try the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex):

```
linear-gradient\([^(]*(\([^)]*\)[^(]*)*[^)]*\)
```

[image: visual]

See [*demo*](https://regex101.com/r/O581sO/1/) in [`https://regex101.com/`](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: that not split into each angel and [color] bro