# swift split css linear-gradient using regex

Tags: swift, regex, linear-gradients

i have css gradient like this:

```
linear-gradient(193deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(78,74,64,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
```

I want to convert it into Swift gradient info like : [colors], angel, [location] using regex.
I tried this regex

```
linear-gradient\([^(]*(\([^)]*\)[^(]*)*[^)]*\)
```

but still not working
https://regex101.com/r/O581sO/1/

My expected output
[ 193,
[2,0,36,1],
0,
[78,74,64,1],
35,
[0,212,255,1],
100
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this expression? This should get you what you wanted in groups

```regex
linear-gradient\((\d+)deg|,\s+(?:(?:rgba\((.*?)\)).+?(\d+)%)+
```